# How do I change the refresh rate of the built-in display?

Tags: mac, refresh-rate

I have a **MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1 Chip, 2020)** and I want to figure out how to stop it from automatically changing the refresh rate. When I'm watching a video, the display will go from, like, 60hz to 30hz and then randomly changes between the two.

This also happens when playing games but it is not the FPS dropping, as I can confirm that games stay at 60FPS when the screen does its random refresh rate change.

I went into the Display settings but couldn't find much. I tried holding Option and clicking scaled, but that didn't show anything new.

So, how do I force the built-in display's refresh rate to 60hz?

Here is what I see when I hold Option and click Scaled.

Preferences > Display (whilst holding Option):

[image: Preferences > Display (whilst holding Option)]

Comment: Is this the "ProMotion" mode? Can you disable or change it using this option panel? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210742

Comment: I think it is ProMotion. Like I said, `I tried holding Option and clicking scaled, but that didn't show anything new.`

Comment: Found something [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/permanently-disable-adaptive-sync-and-force-refresh-rate.2326375/post-30891973) that suggests you can set a refresh using a free app called EasyRes https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/permanently-disable-adaptive-sync-and-force-refresh-rate.2326375/post-30891973

Comment: Thank you. I will do some testing and check if it works.

Comment: Ok, it works thank you. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.